# Poor Graphics3D rendering

Tags: graphics3d

I am rendering a world environment simulation in *Mathematica* with `Graphics3D` code:

```
Show[{
Graphics3D[{
Lighting -> "Neutral",
Green, 
Polygon[{{-10, -10, 0}, {-10, 10, 0}, {10, 10, 0}, {10, -10, 
   0}}],
Red, Cone[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, .1}}, 1/2],
White, 
Table[Sphere[
   Table[{0, 0, 10} + {rx, ry, rz} + {r, r, r/3} /. 
     r :> RandomReal[]*4, {5}], 
   2] /. {rx -> RandomReal[{-20, 20}], 
   ry -> RandomReal[{-20, 20}], rz -> RandomReal[{-1, 3}]}, {30}]
}, Boxed -> False, Background -> Blue, 
ImageSize -> {900, 900*41/54}, SphericalRegion -> True],
ContourPlot3D[
x^2 + y^2 == 10^2, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, 0, .6}, 
Mesh -> None, Lighting -> "Neutral", 
ContourStyle -> Darker[Green]]
}]
```

If the camera is positioned far away from the scene so that everything is in view range, it renders fine:

[image: somewhat cloudy]

However, when I specify the desired camera parameters:

```
ViewVector -> {{0, 0, .1}, {0, 1, .1}}, ViewAngle -> 54 \[Degree]
```

The rendering becomes weird:

[image: weird rendering]

The bottom part of the green rectangle is cut off and the blue background is displayed instead, and the red cone is very weird as well. Is there a way to display this scene properly?

edit:
**Solved** with

```
ViewRange -> {0.1, 100}
```

This is not optimal, because it does not take `0` or `Automatic` for a minimum value, `All` causes the cut-off in the above example, and it does not take `Infinity` or `Automatic` for a maximum value.

Comment: Could be the objects are overlapping and rendering poorly. What happens if you move the cone slightly higher off the 'ground'?

Comment: The cone is then rendered correctly, but the scene is still cut off at the bottom: http://i.imgur.com/qmtF9Of.png

Comment: `ContourPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 == 10^2, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, 0, .6}, Mesh -> None, Lighting -> "Neutral", ContourStyle -> Darker[Green]]` - are you aware that there's a `Cylinder[]` primitive?

Comment: Yes, but it has bottom and top faces, which I don't want displayed in this case.

Comment: In that case, you use `Tube[]` with a suitable setting for `CapForm[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with

```
ViewRange -> {0.1, 100}
```

This is not optimal, because it does not take `0` or `Automatic` for a minimum value, `All` causes the cut-off in the above example, and it does not take `Infinity` or `Automatic` for a maximum value.